# Golf MK4 Window Motor Click and Window wont open

Tags: vw, golf, power-windows, relay

First of all sorry for my english. 
I have a Golf mk4 1.4 16v 2 doors
There are about two weeks that it started to make this click when i try to open the window and it just wont open.
I tryed to contact some store that have used parts and i asked for the window motor. They asked me if my car have 2 or 4 doors, and when I told them that have 2 doors they said no we dont have. Now im looking for the part on ebay but i dont know whats the difference between. The windows motor looks the same. This is the part i found on ebay but im not sure if it gonna work with my car.
Does anyone know if there are differences between a front left motor for a 4-door golf or a front left motor for a 2-door golf.

[image: 1J2959801D FRONT LEFT WINDOW GOLF MK4 MOTOR VW]

Comment: There is a physical difference between front and rear motors on the four door, but I'm not seeing a different listing between a 4dr and 2dr ... It just shows "front" and "rear" difference. I don't know if this helps, but thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: ok so if i want the front left is the same for the 4-door and the 2-door vesion?

Comment: Forgive me for any confusion. I was thinking my comment might cause some. I cannot tell you if the 2dr and 4dr versions are the same for the front, just that the front and rear are different for the 4dr. I mean, they are physically different. To clarify something, is your engine the 1.4L engine? I'm scouring the internet to try and figure this out for you. There is never listed the 2dr hatchback for online parts, but the engine size is. The only one I see listed for a 16v engine for a 1998 is the 1.4L.

Comment: yes, my golf is a 1.4L 16v, thank you for your help

Comment: This is the EXACT same part that my 2001 Jetta 1.8T takes in the front driver side door.

Comment: Are you sure you even need a motor?  The window regulators in those cars are notorious for breaking.  Even if you do need a motor, you probably need a regulator as well.  On the MkIII Jetta the only way to remove a window that won't roll down is to cut the cables on the regulator.

Comment: One important note: the motor (pictured) may not be the problem at all. It may be the regulator. I've replaced 3 of these in my 2001.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you guys for your advices. Yesterday i bought 2 regulators for the 2 doors. Now it works perfectly. 2 days ago the driver's door stuck in central locking and the window motors circuit doesnt pass power to the door lock. I had to open the locked door from the inside then at the moment that i changed the motor, the door opened from the door switch of the central locking.
I found the parts in very good conditions at a used spare parts store for just 12$ each.

Thank you guys,
Have a nice day

P.S. I upvoted every comment :)

Comment: Your the man for coming back and sharing the outcome.  Thanks much  +1